# connect without router cable and without screen

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I just installed raspbian on my new raspberry 3, I did it from my friend's house because I don't have an hdmi screen/cable at my home

When I will arrive at home I will be not able to see it, and I cannot enter in the modem room because is closed (so I cannot plug the ethernet cable and auto-configure it)

I need some help now until I arrive home and now I have an hdmi TV, mouse, and ssh access from my macbook and I can run commands

Answer (score 0):

You could install a WiFi dongle on your hardware, install [wpa_supplicant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wpa_supplicant) and [configure](https://www.debuntu.org/how-to-wifi-roaming-with-wpa-supplicant/) `/etc/network/interfaces` to roam between your preferred networks (eg.: Your home's wifi, yours friend's wifi, work, etc..).

Then, you could access your raspberry through any SSH client, like PuTTy.

Comment: Pi 3 has wifi hardware already

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question:

A) You want to connect your RPi to MacBook.
B) You have a running RPi-3, I assume, originally connected to a friend Wi-Fi.
C) You don't have your home's Wi-Fi password, however I assume the MacBook is Wi-Fi connected.
C) No physical access to the Access Point and no access to switch to provide eth0 access.

So, you want to connect to your Wi-Fi without using the **WPS** auto configure button.
Your options are limited. Your best solution is to find the Wi-Fi password.
In a Windows box connected to the subject Wi-Fi , open a command prompt and then:

```
netsh wlan show profile key=clear name="xxxx"
```

This will show all the past Wi-Fi connection plain text passwords ... no more secrets.

If you mac have Ethernet connectivity, perhaps you can share the Wi-Fi doing  *Internet Connection Sharing* and just plug your RPi to the Ethernet port.

*pd:* If you know the SSID and password of your home Access Point (*router*), you can add as additional network statement on `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` keeping your friend's definition.

```
network={
   ssid="YOUR SSID here"
   scan_ssid=1
   mode=0
   proto=WPA2
   auth_alg=OPEN
   pairwise=CCMP
   group=CCMP
   key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
   psk="YOUR PASSWORD HERE"
   id_str="YOUR COMPUTER ID HERE"
   priority=1
 }
```

Comment: I have last mackbook without ethernet port, but I know my home router's password

Comment: Now I am at home and I am buying an hdmi screen online

Comment: Then for future reference, if you know the SSID and password, just add another network={}  on your supplicant configuration as alternative. You can have as many networks as you need.

Comment: can you show an example please?